# Getting Unresolved reference error while trying to work with Android material3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am getting the below unresolved reference error while trying to build a new Android app using Jetpack Compose and Material3 components.

[image]

I have so far tried the below steps mentioned in [this](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/getting-started) page:

1. Updated dependency of android.material to 1.5.04 or later
2. Ensured compileSDK is 31
3. Ensure comilation with JAVA 8
4. Used AppCompatActivity to extend my MainActivity
5. Invalidated caches and restarted

My gradle code is below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.recoverme"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

in your build.gradle.

[Latest material3 release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3)